# Communication between middleware and route in keystonejs

Tags: node.js, express, keystonejs

I am using keystone and I have productDetail route in which I can add variables in res.locals to be used in templates. Is there a way I can use res.locals (of route file) in middleware.js file? As right now middleware is executing before route, I want route file to be executed first.

This is where middleware is executing in index.js file

```
keystone.pre('routes', middleware.initLocals);
```

And after that we have

```
exports = module.exports = function(app) {
  // Views
  app.get('/', routes.views.index);
  app.get('/product-detail/:product', routes.views.productDetails);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question but this might help. You can run as many custom middleware you want after the `middleware.initLocals` (which apparently runs first). In your `routes/middleware.js` file, you can have, for example, two middleware:

```
exports.middleware0 = function (req, res, next) {
        // Do some stuff
        next();
};

exports.middleware1 = function (req, res, next) {
        // Do some other stuff
        next();
};
```

Then, inside your `routes/index.js` you can chain middleware together:

```
//...
var middleware = require('./middleware');
//...
exports = module.exports = function (app) {
    // Use the middleware0 and middleware1:
    app.get('/product-detail/:product', [middleware.middleware0, middleware.middleware1], routes.views.productDetails);
};
```